# Specify anything in brackets - vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a file that contains texts and inside each text there is a number in parentheses
Is there a way in vscode to select all the numbers in parentheses and delete or replace them in an easy way, I can't do it manually because the scripts exceed 5000

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH5Q8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the search function in VS Code.

1. Click on the magnifying glass, in the sidebar.
2. toggle search details by clicking on the 3 dots in the search pane
3. name your file in the files to include
4. enable regular expression
5. use a regular expression that fits your case, i.e `\(\d+\)`
6. enter a replace text (or leave it empty to remove), in the second input and click replace all

[image: vscode search and replace]

You could also use `sed` to do that.

```bash
sed -E 's/\([0-9]+\)/(something else)/g' file.txt > newfile.txt
```